# VBA open for output permission denied

Tags: vba, excel

Please find my below code where i am getting permission denied error

```
Sub VBA()

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

i = "info"
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("z:\" & i & ".txt", True)

File = "z:\" & i & ".txt"
n = FreeFile()
Open File For Output As #n '''HERE I AM GETTING ERROR
Print #n, s
End Sub
```

Comment: You opened a file with FSO. Then you are trying to open the same file with built-in VBA tools. Use either, not both.

Comment: @GSerg Please guide how can i open and print with FSO.

Comment: I don't think `FileSystemObject` facilitates printing but, even if it did, a "guide" to how to print with it is almost certainly too broad to be on-topic.  Try writing some code and when/if you have a specific problem raise another question.  (@GSerg's comment answers the issues you are currently having.)

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted. I have an identical problem. ```CreateTextFile``` needs to be run, otherwise the file cannot be created. And unless I'm missing something, ```WriteLine``` cannot write when the text has multiple lines itself (e.g. when writing the mail body). Hence ```Open``` is also needed.

Comment: @GerasimosPanagiotakopoulos`Writeline`appends the passed string to the end of the stream and adds a linebreak (vbCrLf or`Chr(10) & Chr(13)`). If the string contains linebreaks too, multiple lines where appended. If you don't want a linebreak to be added at the end use`.Write`instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the file before opening it for a second time.

```
Sub VBA()

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

i = "info"
Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("z:\" & i & ".txt", True)
ts.Close ' this is what you were missing, the file needs to be closed

File = "z:\" & i & ".txt"
n = FreeFile()
Open File For Output As #n 
Print #n, s
End Sub
```

Otherwise your code was correct.

Comment: [Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement?redirectedfrom=MSDN) creates the file if it doesn't exist (except on`Open File For Input`). No need to create one with`fso.CreateTextFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below and pass any number of arguments to it.

```
Public Sub WriteToTextFile(ByVal Filename As String, ParamArray args() As Variant)
    On Error GoTo ErrProc

    Dim hFileDest As Integer
        hFileDest = FreeFile
    Open Filename For Append As #hFileDest

    Dim idx As Integer
    For idx = LBound(args) To UBound(args)
        Print #hFileDest, args(idx)
    Next idx

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
    Close #hFileDest
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrProc:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

To call it:

```
Sub T()
    Dim path_ As String
        path_ = "D:\Test.txt"

    WriteToTextFile path_, "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"
End Sub
```

Output:

```
One
Two
Three
Four
Five
```

Comment: I have resolved the above error with the help of **ts.WriteLine s**

Comment: @sagar I think that ```ts.WriteLine s``` will not work if s does not fit to a line. I'm getting an error message while trying to save the email body

Comment: `idx`should be a`Long`or you are limited to 2^15-1 (32767) lines (Ok, usually should be sufficent, but at least mention that limit) I would just write all at once with`Print #hFileDest, Join(args,vbCrLf)`